# ROS Answers SE migration: rosmake error

Tags: rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi

i am getting error below when i am trying to rosmake rviz

```
[rosbuild] Building package rviz
[rosbuild] Cached build flags older than manifests; calling rospack to get flags
Failed to invoke /opt/ros/fuerte/bin/rospack cflags-only-I;--deps-only rviz
Package sensor_msgs was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `sensor_msgs.pc' to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'sensor_msgs' found

CMake Error at /opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:129 (message):
```

It is complaining that sensor_msgs.pc is not in PKG_CONFIG_PATH
However, the sensor_msgs.pc is in the config path when i check it.

```
:~/fuerte_workspace$ echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH
/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/pkgconfig:/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/pkgconfig:/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/pkgconfig

:~/fuerte_workspace$ find /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/pkgconfig | grep 
sensor/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/pkgconfig/sensor_msgs.pc
```

Does anyone encounter this issue before?
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49315/rosmake-error/) by [clee](https://answers.ros.org/users/3682/clee/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-11-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-11-28**:
Looks like you are sourcing /opt/ros/fuerte/setup.sh three times. That might cause problems. But, @Lorenz is right: just install `ros-fuerte-visualization`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Why are you building rviz from source? Just install the debian package:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-visualization
```

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-11-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0